# Updated snes9x today, it crashes when I try to open a rom now

Tags: crash

I just finished updating snes9x on Ubuntu Mate 17.04.  When I try to open a recent game, it instantly crashes, leaving with me with no error message or anything.  I tried looking at the log, but I'm not sure what I'm even looking at there.  Is there a way to figure out what is causing the error or even chosing an exact version to install (the previous version)?  I'd love to not to have to start my game over again in zsnes (unless I can figure out how to load snes9x saved state).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very good reasons to choose Snes9x instead, I suggest using ZNES that works flawlessly on my machine (I have revision 1.51, USB joypad works fine).

Comment: I prefer it as well, and I don't remember exactly why I switched to snes9x.  Do you know if there is a way to load a save state from snes9x in zsnes?

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to load .SRM files on ZSNES (AFAIK SNES9X saves files in that format): http://board.zsnes.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=12875